# Usage of concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor throws timeout exception always in aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-3.7, concurrent.futures

I have the following code in `aws` `lambda` to get response from an API until the status is complete. I have used the `ThreadPoolExecutor` from `concurrent.futures`.

Here is the sample code.

```
import requests
import json
import concurrent.futures

def copy_url(headers,data):
   collectionStatus = 'INITIATED'
   retries = 0
   print(" The data to be copied is ",data)
   while (collectionStatus != 'COMPLETED' or retries <= 50):
       r = requests.post(
              url=URL,
              headers=headers,
              data=json.dumps(data))
       final_status= r.json().get('status').pop().get('status')
       retries += 1
       print(" The collection status is",final_status)


with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    future = executor.submit(copy_url,headers,data)
    return_value = future.result()
```

I had already implemented this using regular threads in python. However, since I wanted a return value from the thread tried implementing this. Though this works perfectly in `pycharm`, it always throws a timeout error in `aws` `lambda`.

Could someone please explain why this happens only in `aws-lambda`?

Note : I have already tried increasing the `lambda` timeout value. This happens only when `threadpoolexecutor` is implemented. When I comment out that code it works fine.Also it works fine with the regular python thread implementation

Comment: thanks for documenting this problem - faced the same issue.

Comment: My issue was resolved after increasing timeout from 3 seconds to 10 seconds - it took a long time first time this new code ran, but consequent runs were under 3 seconds. Without letting it complete once, it was always timing out.

Comment: @RobertMcPythons Thanks for sharing. In my case, the API response took longer time (around 10 minutes) to complete the execution which I cant afford as I have to send a response back to API gateway connected to my lambda. That's when I tried mulitprocessing which didn't work either for the reason I have shared in my answer.So I had to change the design.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I changed the implementation to listening to a `SQS` trigger rather than waiting for the response from an API (The API is handled by a different component and response will take a significant amount of time)

Looks like we should avoid using parallel processing tasks with python in aws lambda.

From the AWS [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/parallel-processing-in-python-with-aws-lambda/):

> The multiprocessing module that comes with Python lets you run
>   multiple processes in parallel. Due to the Lambda execution
>   environment not having /dev/shm (shared memory for processes) support,
>   you can’t use multiprocessing.Queue or multiprocessing.Pool.

If `multiprocessing` ought to be used, only PIPE is supported.

Answer (score 0):

The question was related to multithread execution, but the AWS documentation listed on the answer is related to multiprocessing, they are different implementations.

- Multiprocess will open a new child process to execute the operation
- Multithread will create a new thread on the same process to execute the operation.

More information on this answer: [Multiprocessing vs Threading Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3044626/1523634)